# Drawing Horizontal Line for high and low for a specific date using array

Tags: tradingview-api

I have a script which draws vertical lines for a specific date which are hard coded in script in the form of an array. Now I wanted to draw horizonal lines for high and low of those dates

I tried using new line function but its taking only one input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z4Yp.png)  in attached image u can see vertical lines , for same dates i wanted horizontal lines for high and low

Comment: In image u can see vertical dotted lines for same i wanted to draw horizontal lines below is the script.

Comment: indicator("Sun venus Mercury Jupiter Aspects", overlay=true,max_lines_count=500)

var dates = array.new<int>(500)
//sun Mercury
array.set(dates,0,timestamp('07-Jan-2023 00:01')) //conjunction 
array.set(dates,1,timestamp('17-Mar-2023 00:01')) //conjunction 
array.set(dates,2,timestamp('1-May-2023 00:01')) //conjunction 
i = 0
if barstate.islast
    while i < array.size(dates)
        lineDate = (array.get(dates, i))
        i += 1
        line.new(x1=lineDate, y1=high, x2=lineDate, y2=low, extend=extend.both,style=line.style_dotted, color=color.blue, width=1, xloc=xloc.bar_time)